ESP32 doesn't get enough power over a long cable
I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this since it is more of an electrical issue rather than coding issue.
I have an ESP32 that I power using my computer's power supply (which can supply steady 5V@3A.)  When I connect it directly to the power supply (with simple jumper wires) it works flawlessly.  When connecting it through a 1.5 meter DB9 serial cable, it doesn't seem to supply enough current for the WiFi to turn on so the ESP continuously restarts itself.
The wiring is: 5V and ground from the computer going to a DB9 breakout board, then through the cable to another breakout board and finally to the ESP32 5V and ground pins.
I already verified that the voltage is 5V at each end of the cable, so I guess the issue is with the current but I have no clue about this stuff so I am not sure how to debug it any further.
I chose a DB9 serial cable since I thought it being a standard cable would already have protection from interference and stuff like that.
Some more info
The ESP32 runs on 3.3V and 0.5A (it has a built-in regulator to convert the 5V to 3.3V.)
I added a 6.3V 1500uF capacitor to the ESP32 end, but it didn't help.
My setup is basically an ESP32 that controls the power button on the PC so I can turn it on remotely, and I just thought I can save myself an extra power cable by simply using the power for the power supply.
Edit #2
I just tried to use other wires for 5V and GND, but the ESP still turns on but isn't able to turn on the WiFi (the WiFi LED doesn't turn on.)
The wiring is currently two wires in the DB9 are used for 5V and two wires are used for GND (the other wires are used for other things.)
And on the ESP end, I use WAGO connector to converge the two 5V and the two GND wires back to one wire each.
Correct me if I wired it wrong.
Last edit
In an unsurprising and anticlimactic turn of events, the cause was the cable. Even though it supplied a stable 5.2V on both ends, it just wasn't thick enough to prevent voltage drop.
Since I don't have quick access to a buck/boost converter, I can't really test if sending a higher voltage would have solved this issue.
For now, I used another much thicker cable for power and it works great. I might try a thicker DB9 cable in the future (or some of the other suggestions in this thread.)

Sounds like voltage drop. How much current does it use?

I would use a buck dc-dc converter module to turn the 5v into 3.3v, then feed that to your esp dev board's 3v pin. That reduces the 5v current and adds some caps to the  circuit. If it still doesn't work, send 12v to the buck converter instead of 5v.

Regarding edits: is the 5V stable at the receiving end or does it fluctuate? Measure with your scope.

@Lundin stable 5.2V

@dandavis The ESP already has a regulator to step down from 5V to 3V, would buck converter be more efficient?

The built in turns 1/3rd of the power it uses into wasted heat. Taken another way, 1A to the on-board LDO's output is 1A on the input, but on a SMPS it would be (3.3/5), aka 0.66A on the input (minus ~10% losses), and with an SMPS and 12v, 1A out would only be 0.27A in. You can also turn 12v into 5v for about a 55% "discount", and feed 5v in to the MCU as you do already, if you need 5v for other parts.

The reason they are using a linear regulator for 3V is very likely because it's an RF supply, where a buck converter is unsuitable.

Use a multimeter to measure the 5V pin on the ESP32 while it's trying to turn on the WiFi. See if the voltage drops significantly (below 4.7V or so). If it does, it's a clear sign that the cable isn’t delivering enough current.

@liaifat85 since the current pulses are only a ms or 2, a multimeter probably won't show any voltage change at all, it's WAY to fast.

The ESP32 draws high-current, short-term spikes of current when it transmits, and with a longer cable, these can cause the voltage to sag significantly. This can be improved by adding a large reservoir capacitor — at least 1000 µF — at the ESP32 end.

If this is the problem then the more sensible approach might be to provide a higher voltage like industry standard 24V and then let each board have a decentralized voltage converter. But maybe re-design isn't an option.

I added 6.3V 1500uF capacitor on the ESP32 side, but it didn't help...

Then you'll need something more elaborate, along the lines of what @Lundin is suggesting. Perhaps a buck/boost converter between the cable and the ESP32? Can you provide more details about your setup (edit into your question)?

@DaveTweed do you mean boosting the voltage from the power supply and then lowering it back to 5V on the ESP side?

That would work, too, but I was thinking about the sort of module used with batteries that can have the output voltage either lower or higher than the input voltage. It would cope better with the voltage sags than the simple regulator on the ESP32 itself.

Cables for beginners:

Most cables you'll ever use are using copper material. There are no ideal materials and so all materials have some losses/resistances.
Losses will become more significant the longer the cable is, but also the thinner it is. So the thicker and shorter the cable, the more ideal it is for carrying high currents.
When providing high currents over a longer copper cable, we get something called voltage drop, resulting in a lower voltage at the end of the cable than we had at the beginning.
If the current is too high in relation to the diameter and length, the cable will get warm. Which is bad, as it may ultimately lead to a cable fire.
Knowing the copper wire diameter, we can calculate the voltage drop for a given current. There's naturally formulas for this - check out some online voltage drop calculator where some of the theory is summarized.
There are a couple of different standards for cable diameters. These refer to the copper diameter of the conductor and not the copper + insulation diameter. Most common is the AWG system (American Wire Gauge) which is used the most world-wide and often the one specified by connector manufacturers. In Europe there's a mm2 (square millimeter) system as well.

General best practices:

Design decentralized systems where you provide a higher raw voltage than what's required. Each subsystem then uses local voltage regulators to step the voltage down to their own needs. Very commonly 24 VDC is used for this. And then boards use buck regulators to take this down to something like 5VDC or 3.3VDC. Even if we have a board drawing some 10A and supply it over a very long cable, the voltage drop still won't be large enough to get anywhere near 5V.
Dodging the problem of voltage drop by doubling the amount of cables is bad practice and forbidden in certain applications (230 VAC or larger in particular). By doubling the amount of cables, you do get the equivalent of 2x the area and therefore 2x the current capacity. But if one cable would get cut off/have poor soldering etc., then all current goes through the other one. And if you haven't accounted for that, it will get hot and potentially you get a cable fire.

A plain "serial cable" DB9 male to DB9 female has a thickness somewhere around AWG 24 to 28 - they are signal cables and might not be sufficient for whatever currents you need.
So the most sensible solutions to the problem is either to provide a higher supply voltage or a thicker cable.

I only connect an ESP32 which uses about 0.5A, which is not much and (from my understanding) should be ok for AWG 24 cable (all my jumper wires are AWG 24 and I never had an issue).

I wouldn't assume that a cheap cable was copper.  Copper covered aluminium and copper covered steel are cheap alternatives, and used by suppliers at the less respectable and of the market.

@SagiZiv 0.5A continuous/average or peak? You have to design for the peak use.

the esp32 draws an avg of about 85ma, with 1ms spikes approaching 2-400ma.


If your power source is adequate (supplies more current then is needed to run the ESP32 and the embedded WIFI radio):

There may be an easy solution to this problem. Use 2 pins for power and do the same for ground. Using 2 of the same length/gauge wire is expected to double the current capacity.
Make sure to individually test each pin pair you intend to use verifying they are connected end-to-end. And that they do not switch pins from one end to the other. RS232 cables are not all alike. Evidently the "RS" in "RS232" stands for "Recommended Standard".

If your power supply can not supply the necessary current, consider replacing it with one that can:


My setup is basically an ESP32 that controls the power button on the PC so I can turn it on remotely, and I just thought I can save myself an extra power cable by simply using the power for the power supply.

By "the power supply" are you referring to the computer's always on power pin (green in most cases). This is meant to only be used to turn on the computer. Likely it does not have the current capacity to power an embedded processor w/a WIFI transmitter.

...or just use the correct AWG size on the cables, suitable for the expected current. Which would be the proper electrical engineering solution to the problem.

That's an interesting solution, I'll try it later

@Lundin The ESP32 only uses ~0.5A, so I'm pretty sure the wires in the DB9 cable are the correct AWG size.

@SagiZiv One disturbing trend I’ve discovered recently is that several of the cheap low voltage cables made nowadays use either steel or brass wire with a thin coat of copper.Steel is easy to rule out because you can use a magnet to see if any of the wire strands attract to it.Brass is harder to identify and I can only do it easily if my buddy zaps it with his XRF gun.In either case, what usually prompts me that sometimes is wrong is when I have to cut the cable and solder to it it’s very difficult to solder to. Anyway, might still be worth making your own cable to rule this possibility out.

@SagiZiv said "The ESP32 only uses ~0.5A". That most likely is an average. Unfortunately you need to plan for peak current draw. No mater if that's from speedy calculations or a radio (in this case it's probably the WIFI radio). Look, you can try the most popular answer and buy a 1000uF capacitor. Or, try my idea. You already have the DB9 RS232 cable ... just use more wires to deliver the power and see what happens. OTOH, you could have an undersized power supply. I try to use a power source w/2x the PEAK current demand of what I am driving.

@st2000 I do use the 5V standby of the power supply and the specs show it can supply up to 3A. And connecting to it directly works great, I guess I just need to try using more than one wire.

@st2000 Just used another wire for ground and 5V, updating my question

I see where you said you are using the standby power supply which is rated up to 3A. I am still skeptical and wonder how well it is working. Just for testing, I would next substitute an independent power supply and try again.

I'll add this now rather than wait: My only other current thought is that you are picking up noise on the long run of power wire when you turn on the ESP32's WIFI (unless you are turning on something else that you haven't mentioned here). I think this possibility is unlikely. But to filter out high frequency noise you need small bypass capacitors across the power supply at the ESP32 end of the cable.
